# Gulp is not updating css file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

When I'm changing css file and then open "bundle.min.css", there are no changes applied, no errors are displayed in the console, what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.css')
    .pipe(concatCss("bundle.css"))
    .pipe(minifyCss(''))
    .pipe(rename("bundle.min.css"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions'],cascade: false}))
    .pipe(notify("Gulp Done!"));
});


gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('*.css', ['default'])
});
```

Comment: Are you starting your watch task with `gulp watch`?

Comment: I suppose you should only edit the source file, which is `bundle.css`. The corresponding minified version of the file is something built by gulp, so you should leave it as is.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren yes

Comment: I see you're watching *.css. If you have a css file inside a subdirectory, then you're not watching it, so your problem makes sense. Just update your watch and src path from *.css to ./**/*.css. This will recursively watch all css files in your project ;-)